# Angular: How to share a component between different components in different modules and vice versa

Tags: angular, module, angular-components, angular-module

How to share a component between different components in different modules share the components in the different modules with the shared component.

I have four modules. Module A with component A, Module B with component B, Module C with component C, and Module D with component D. Modules B, C and D each import Module A in order to access component A. But there is an issue, component A needs the respective components that use it. For example component A needs component B when being used by component B.

Is there a way to make it work without making the modules B, C and D each have their own copy of component A?

Comment: is it not possible for you to import A and B in the Same Module so that they can communicate with each other

Comment: @FahadRehman Thanks. I understand that. I was looking for another way to achieve my objective. The accepted answer has shown me that other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a common requirement. Here let me explain it a little.

Angular allows one component to be declared in **one and only one module**. And if that component is required in another module, you'll have to import that module in the imports array of the module that needs that component.

Now if **Component A** is in Module A, and **Component B** in Module B and both needs each other, and you import **Module A** in **Module B**, and **Module B** in **Module A**, then you fall in circular reference trap.

To resolve this issue, you'll have to introduce a **new module**, and declare all such components in this **new module**, and let this **new module** to be imported in the modules that need the components.

Lets say my this new module name is **LoaderSharedModule**, it would look like this

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [Component1, Component2, Component3],
  exports: [Component1, Component2, Component3]
})
export class LoaderSharedModule { }
```

The modules would import this module to start using Component1,2,3.. like this

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LoaderSharedModule
  ],
})
export class Module1 { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LoaderSharedModule
  ],
})
export class Module2 { }

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LoaderSharedModule
  ],
})
export class Module3 { }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I honestly thought there was no way. I was about to create duplicate components. I am glad I asked. Thanks.